# C: undefined reference... to library used successfully elsewhere

Tags: c, compilation

I am trying to compile a C++ project (openFrameworks + CodeBlocks), using an external C library. I get "undefined reference" error, although I succesfully compile and use the library elsewhere.

The code consists of sources main.cpp, testApp.cpp and header files, including one for my library "myprocessing". When I `make` , the code is compiled and dies at linking with error

```
obj/i686Release/./src/testApp.o: In function `testApp::update()':
testApp.cpp:(.text+0x261): undefined reference to `gauss_5(datarect_t)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/faceGrabber] Error 1
```

where `gauss_5` is my library function, and it is called in `testApp.cpp` (header with declarations is included there).

Below I paste the `make` commands used to compile the code, generated by CodeBlocks (I strip it for clarity)

```
# compiling object for:  ./src/testApp.cpp

g++ -c -g  [some -I...] -DOF_USING_GTK -DOF_USING_MPG123 -Wall 
  -fexceptions -I.  -Ilib/ -MMD -MP -MFobj/i686Debug/./src/testApp.d 
  -MTobj/i686Debug/./src/testApp.d -oobj/i686Debug/./src/testApp.o 
  -c ./src/testApp.cpp

# compiling object for:  ./src/main.cpp

g++ -c -g -pthread [some -I...]  -DOF_USING_GTK -DOF_USING_MPG123
  -Wall -fexceptions -I.   -Ilib/ -MMD -MP -MFobj/i686Debug/./src/main.d
  -MTobj/i686Debug/./src/main.d -oobj/i686Debug/./src/main.o
  -c ./src/main.cpp

# linking bin/faceGrabber_debug . ./src ./lib

g++ -o bin/faceGrabber_debug obj/i686Debug/./src/testApp.o
  obj/i686Debug/./src/main.o   -Wl,-rpath=./libs -Llib/ -lz
  -lmyprocessing [some libs...]
```

Note that my library is referenced (`-lmyprocessing`) in the last, linking step. So, all the headers and libraries are found by the compiler, but somehow they are not compiled-in.

I tried both `.a` static and `.so` dynamic files for myprocessing, unsuccessfully. As I mentioned, I use the same library in other project (outside openFrameworks and CodeBlocks) and it works.

Comment: Use `g++ -v` to understand what `g++` is actually doing.

Comment: Your directory structure would help, is your .so file in ./lib (relative to your Makefile)?

Comment: Yes, it is there. Otherwise the linker would complain, I suppose. besides, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that the library is written in C. However, the fact that the linker is able to print out the type of the argument to `gauss_5()` suggests that it's working with the mangled, C++ name of the function.

I suspect you might be missing `extern "C" { ... }` guards around your C header.